# creating a .NET application that simulates a FIFO on a web server

Tags: .net, webserver

I need to build a windows server side application that will be responsible for receiving large files and process them (the process action will take around 3 hours).

Can someone tell me what's the best approach in a case like this (windows service probably) and in that case, how to tell the service that a new file is available for processing?

ps: the process action cannot be parallel processing

**edit**: After looking to some answers, I'll try to rephrase the problem. The upload part is already working. My problem is I have to run an algorithm over the file after the upload. This algorithm takes aroud 3 hours to process a single file. I want to ensure that the files to process are stored somewhere (in memory, on a db, it really doesn't matter where) and it will only analyze the next one when the previous one finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a console application that when it's idle (not processing any file) decides which file should process next and launches it.

The application is configured to start up when the machine is booted.

Answer (score 0):

Use some simple data collection to collect the threads of each process.

For example, you can use like a List and define variable which is an index of thread that is currently processing.

Comment: With either option I choose, I'll have to use a data collection to know which's files I have to process. My problem here is to decide if i build a windows service, a console application, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting up a ftp server, and perhaps a `FileSystemWatcher` to pick up files as they are uploaded and process them

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: Currently i have a ASP file that uploads the file to the server and process them when the upload ends. The problem is if n users decide to upload n files simultaneous. The process is processor heavy so it should be made in a sequential way ( like a FIFO ).

Comment: @Daniel. What are you wanting to make 'FIFO'? the webserver, the image processing? I dont think you have perhaps thought about this enough.
Uploading a file should not be heavy on the processor, is this the processing that you are saying is heavy on the processor?

Comment: Uploading a file is not heavy on the processor, but each file is around 600mb of raw data. The upload part is already working, my problem here is on the post upload processor. We run an algorithm over the file that takes around 3hours to process. If n people try to upload files of raw data simultaneous, it will be a lot worse. I just want a way to process the arriving files as a FIFO.

Comment: @Daniel. With 600mb, I would definitely recommend changing your ASP page to a FTP solution instead, its what its designed for.
Even if you stick with the ASP page, save the file to a disk, then write a windows service that uses a FileSystemWatcher. when a new file is placed in the directory, the service can process it. write it so that it only processes one at once. Make sure you test the load that the service places on the server. the priority of services can be configured to reduce the load.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [BITS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362708%28VS.85%29.aspx) to upload the files.  There is a C# wrapper for that API [here](http://sharpbits.codeplex.com/releases/view/9134).

Note that for upload there is a [server-side dependency on IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363130%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

BITS is the technology used (in download mode) to automatically put required security and other updates onto your machine from update.microsoft.com.

Comment: Currently i have a ASP file that uploads the file to the server and process them when the upload ends. The problem is if n users decide to upload n files simultaneous. The process is processor heavy so it should be made in a sequential way ( like a FIFO ).

Comment: Yes, I think using BITS is more client-driven.  Sounds like you need some sequencing logic on the server that this will not provide, sorry.